# Chrome incising system memory allocation while using Single page application

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory, memory-management, single-page-application

I’m developing Single page application where all content on the portal is swap by JavaScript and get by AJAX call. Main content of the page is interactive canvas where the content of the 5 layers of canvas with redrawing content based on data get by AJAX call.
Problem:
I make about 30 click on the canvas and allocated system  memory grew by 1,5 GB. None of the process in the task manager don’t show that allocate this memory. When I reload (F5) the page  the allocated system memory immediately return to normal (free the 1.5GB). 
Second way to retrieve the allocate memory is to stay on the page without any activity for about 30min and the allocated system memory return to normal. It is decrease steadily, not like on reloading the page. 
Of course closing the web browser also ‘help’.
What could help me:
- How to check with process allocate the memory?
- Any idea what could allocate the memory?
- Any idea how to force memory to free ?
Environment:
- Windows 7 Enterprise (64bit)
- IIS 7
- SQL Server 2012 (11.0.2100)
- Chrome 27.0.1453.94 
- Application is develop in Visual Studo 2010 with:
  - MVC 4

**EDIT 06-06-2013**
hear some example from tab chrome://memory-redirect/ 
after enter the application

```
                                            Memory                  Virtual memory  
PID     Name                                Private     Shared      Total       Private     Mapped
2116    Browser                             72608k      29688k      102296k     81680k      74404k
4756    GPU                                 55184k      13088k      68272k      69604k      21216k
4068    Tab (Chrome) - About Memory         9456k       65352k      74808k      16224k      17628k
176     Tab - Applicastion tab              29876k      66552k      96428k      39700k      19684k
                                        Σ   167124k                 341804k     207208k     132932k
```

Phisical memory usage - Task Manager:   **2,59 GB**

After 30 interactions on canvas

```
                                           Memory                  Virtual memory  
PID     Name                                Private     Shared      Total       Private     Mapped
2116    Browser                             81976k      42104k      124080k     89964k      95596k
4756    GPU                                 68136k      14176k      82312k      81548k      21452k
4068    Tab (Chrome) - About Memory         10816k      65408k      76224k      17372k      17632k
176     Tab - Applicastion tab              56180k      67644k      123824k     66224k      19688k
                                        Σ   217108k                 406440k     255108k     154368k
```

Phisical memory usage - Task Manager:   **4.63 GB**

From this calculation tables I see that java- leel can’t by larger then 64636 kB  => 64MB => 0,064 GB. So my question is what for are allocate the rest of the memory almost 2 GB.
I guess it is connected with Chrome because this memory is release on page reload

Answer (score 1):

Overview how one could produce javascript memory leaks:

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-jsmemory/
- http://javascript.info/tutorial/memory-leaks
- http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closuresleak/

Possible tools: (Some taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4949098/510711))

- Chrome: https://code.google.com/p/leak-finder-for-javascript/
- Mozilla: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Performance%3aLeak_Tools
- IE: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gpde/archive/2009/08/03/javascript-memory-leak-detector-v2.aspx

Comment: I know that my application may have memory leek in java script. I want to take care of it later. But if it was just memory leek in java script ti would see rising memory allocation in "java run-time environment" or "Chrome" and it not happen. Or I thing wrong?

Comment: If you see increasing memory for each click you do not free all resources while requesting new memory. That's a leak :) Java run-time environment sounds like Java, not JavaScript. You could try to take a look at chrome://memory-redirect/ in your Chrome for more information about the memory usage of chrome.

Comment: I edit the main question and add data form chrome://memory-redirect/